# How to include cmd in my program (and not only running a single command)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd

I included a cmd in my program, but I can't use commands like "cd" or "@echo off" because it starts a new cmd for every command

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
{
    Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmd.Start();
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
    cmd.StandardInput.Close();
    cmd.WaitForExit();

    richTextBox1.Text = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

What it should be like: if you tipe in a command in textbox1 and press enter, richtextbox1 should display the output, and you can tipe in the next command

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true It shows how you can run multiple commands on a single line. Simply create a string with the appropriate separation characters and pass all the commands in at once.

Comment: but if you want to see the output before you tipe in the next command (like dir)

Comment: You could create a temporary batch inside your program and then run that one, however, without really knowing what you wish to do, it's a bit hard to suggest more

Comment: It starts one every time because you create the CMD window every time.  Move your Process cmd outside of the method and make it a class variable that you can utilize over and over and not create it each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate command line into your application I would recommend launching it in the background and then just feed it's input stream and read it's output.

This way you will create kind of a pipeline.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(process.StandardInput);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(process.StandardOutput);
```

Store reference to these streams and just use it like :

```
writer.WriteLine("dir");
string line = reader.ReadLine ();
```

This method will be more efficient then running command line each time to just process one command.